# Putting .class files in war folder by someway

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, build, war

This is relatively a simple question. 
I am building a web application and I have to put .class files for the project into my war file which is getting deployed.
So I want to put the complied version of class files into the war file folder every time I make changes to source code.
How this can be done with using command line class compilation.

I think Apache ANT maybe useful for that. I have not worked with it before.
Can someone tell if it that is the way to go about this thing ?

If yes, does anyone have tutorial for doing the same using Ant?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, this is what I should have done -> go to the java build path and put the path there where you want to put .class files in the source section. So that you can easily get the latest class files in the war folder ! No need of Ant/Maven in it.

Comment: Anuj - Your answer actually deviates from what you expected in the posting.

Answer (score 2):

You have a great tutorial on using ANT at
[***Tutorial: Hello World with Apache Ant***](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

Before that you may want to understand what ANT is and how to use it? So read
[***Apache Ant™ 1.8.2 Manual***](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should start thinking about using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for your builds.

Maven uses [*Convention over configuration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) which means that there are a few steps to follow where one major thing is the layout of the source tree.

For your concern this is a simple way of setting up what you need:

`directory layout`

```
+- pom.xml
  +- src
    +- main
      +- java
      +- resources
      +- webapp
        +- WEB-INF
          +- web.xml
```

Where your `pom.xml` will look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q11314171</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>webapp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If you install Maven then all you need to do in your root folder (where the `pom.xml` file resides) is to issue `mvn install`.

Then you will have a `war` file in the newly created `target` folder. This `war` file will contain the compiled classes that was in your `src/main/java` path along with necessary resource files.

Comment: @Downvoter OK, thanks for that. Now I know what's wrong with my answer... There was no Maven tag on the question? Too long answer? Off-topic? Thanks again!

Comment: The downvoter is probably and ant nut.  I say whatever gets the job done.  I've used both, and each has their pluses and minuses.